# My regex isn't recognized in Cucumber -- help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, cucumber

So this is a really newby question.

I have a step that looks like this:

```
Then /^I should see ((phrase 1) | (phrase 2))$/ do
  #stuff
end
```

After that, I have a step that looks like this:

```
Then /^I should see phrase 3$/ do
  And %{I should see phrase 2}
end
```

I'm trying to test a registration flow.

`phrase 1` describes the required information that needs to be filled out and I need to verify that they show up the in the user's profile.

`phrase 3` describes the required *and* optional information the user fills out. The optional information should aslo show up in the user's profile and I wanna test that that also shows up.

I don't want to copy and paste the stuff from the first step, so I re-phrased `phrase 1` so that it makes sense to be called from the `phrase 3` step, but I don't know how to properly refer to it in the first step to get it to work. All I get from Cucumber is that `I should see phrase 2` is undefined.

What's the right way to get this work? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whitespace characters are very important in regex's

With whitespace at either end of the pipe you need to use this step:

```
Then %{I should see phrase 1 }
```

or

```
Then %{I should see  phrase 2}
```

(Note that extra space at the end on the first one, and between `see` and `phrase2` on the second one).  The regex is still looking for those space characters where you specified them to be.

Your regex would need to be changed to:

```
Then /^I should see (phrase 1|phrase 2)$/ do |phrase_name|

end
```

The `|` symbol in regex will match *either* all characters on the left side, *or* all characters on the right side (the parantheses of course bounds it so it doesn't take the entire string).

Also you have to pass the value to your block, as I did with `phrase_name` when you use parenthesis in this manner.  Although I would probably rather see the step defined this way:

```
Then /^I should see phrase ([\d]+)$/ do |phrase_number|

end
```

So that it will match for all three of your phrase types, and you wouldn't need the phrase 1 definition anymore.  [\d]+ will match any numerical character 1 or more times.

Then you can do whatever you need to do based on the phrase_number that was sent.  I'd be interested to see your scenario definition though, I'm not sure if you're going about cuking it correctly based on this information.  Maybe I could get some context if I saw the rest of the story.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up implementing something like your `phrase_number` suggestion. :)